# Install latest x86 Ubuntu on a x64 UEFI system

Tags: ubuntu, system-installation, grub, uefi, x86

I currently have to configure my PC so that I can boot Windows 10 and Linux (Ubuntu) in parallel. Up to now, I've managed to arrange the dual boot of Windows 10 and the x64 Ubuntu 1804 LTS. 
However, I also need to add the x86 Ubuntu 1804 LTS version to the GRUB bootmanager. Since Ubuntu doesn't provide a regular x86 .iso file for the Ubuntu installation, I've found a file called "mini.iso" on the internet.

Unfortunately the formatting with the "mini.iso" of my USB-Drive provides only the option for the MBR partition scheme, which makes the USB drive non-visible under UEFI mode.

That raises the question, whether it is possible to install the x86 Ubuntu under UEFI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### General information about 32-bit Ubuntu in UEFI mode

It is possible too boot a persistent live drive with for example Lubuntu 18.04.1 LTS from a 32-bit (i386) iso file in UEFI mode as well as in BIOS mode, when [created with mkusb with the setting 'upefi' (usb-pack-efi)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent#Method_developed_from_.27grub-n-iso.27).

So it is possible to boot a standard Ubuntu based 32-bit system in UEFI mode (but not with secure boot, because the kernels are not signed for secure boot). There are Ubuntu based distros (e.g. LXLE) and also some Debian based distros which have 32-bit iso files that boot in UEFI mode as well as in BIOS mode.

### Try the following method to make 32-bit Ubuntu work in UEFI mode

- I suggest that you install your 32-bit system from the Ubuntu `mini.iso` in BIOS mode (to create a multiboot drive).
- Check that it works in BIOS mode
- Switch to UEFI mode
- Boot into Ubuntu 64-bit
- Run

  ```
  sudo update-grub
  ```
- Check that it recognizes the new 32-bit Ubuntu system
- Reboot and select the new 32-bit Ubuntu system (still in UEFI mode)

Good luck :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your hint solved my problems.

Comment: @RatbaldMeyer, You are welcome and good luck with the 32-bit system in UEFI mode :-)

Answer (score 2):

In the BIOS boot mode, a 32-bit x86 system first starts running in a 16-bit emulation mode, and the kernel needs to "shift up" to 32-bit mode. A 64-bit capable x86 system likewise starts in 16-bit emulation mode, but it can choose to shift up to either 32-bit or full 64-bit mode.

On the other hand, UEFI on x86 can be either 64-bit (x64) or 32-bit (ia32). Some older x86 Macs and quite a few mini laptops implement a 32-bit UEFI on a system that is otherwise 64-bit capable. To support these systems, there is a possibility to either load a 32-bit kernel to stay in 32-bit mode, or to load a 64-bit kernel and "shift up" to full 64-bit mode.

But I have not heard about any support to start in native 64-bit UEFI mode and "shift down" to 32-bit mode from there for the kernel. So I would think it is not possible. However, I would be happy to be proven wrong here.

Remember that a 64-bit x86 kernel is usually fully capable of running 32-bit x86 binaries, as long as 32-bit versions of any necessary libraries have been installed. So depending on what you need the 32-bit support for, you might not necessarily need an entire 32-bit OS installation.

You might just need to run `dpkg --add-architecture i386` on your 64-bit Ubuntu installation, and then add 32-bit versions of any libraries required by the 32-bit software you need to run, with e.g. `apt install <package_name>:i386`. This is known as the basic [Multiarch](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultiArch) setup in Debian, Ubuntu and related distributions.

If you need the capability to build 32-bit software from source code, you might want to look at the [Multiarch Cross-building specification](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MultiarchCross).